# Using foreach() in R to speed up loop for ggplot2

Tags: r, foreach, plot, parallel-processing, ggplot2

I would like to create a PDF file containing hundreds of plots in a certain order.

My strategy was using foreach() and storing each ggplot2 object into the output list, and then printing each ggplot2 object to the output file.

For example, I would like to plot a histogram of prices for every factor "carat" in the diamonds dataset:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(foreach)  # for parallelization
library(doParallel)  # for parallelization

#setup parallel backend to use 4 processors
cl<-makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)

# use diamonds dataset
carats.summary <- ddply(diamonds, .(carat), summarise, count = length(carat))

m.list <- foreach(i = 1:length(carats.summary$carat),
                  .packages = "ggplot2") %dopar% {
                    jcarat = carats.summary$carat[i]
                    m <- ggplot(subset(diamonds, carat == jcarat), aes(x = price)) +
                      geom_histogram()
                    print(m)
}
```

With this code, I am hoping to create a list of ggplot2 objects which I can then save into a single pdf file (for example using `pdf()`) in an ordered manner (for example, in ascending carats).

However, running this results in an error message:

```
Error in serialize(data, node$con) : error writing to connection
```

I suspect this is due to the fact that if I tried to append the ggplot2 object to a list, I would get a warning message like this:

```
lst <- vector(mode = "list")
lst[1] <- m


Warning message:
In lst[1] <- m :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Although this is pure speculation and I could be wrong.

Does anybody have an idea how to use `foreach()` to save `ggplot2` objects onto a list? Or some way to parallelize `for` loops involving `ggplot2`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a good point. `lst[[1]] <- m` would work, but I am not sure how I can translate that to my `foreach()` loop. Maybe I'll look into the `.combine` options in the documentation.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, that comment wasn't entirely relevant. I'm working on an actual answer now.

Comment: Nevermind, @MrFlick pointed out your problem. You could probably throw in a call to `ggsave` right inside the `foreach` loop, or do something less pretty like `sapply(1:length(m.list),function(x){
  pdf(file=paste0(
    "F:/TempDir/Plot_",x,".pdf"));
  print(m.list[[x]]);
  dev.off();
})` afterwards (substituting the appropriate file path for my `"F:/TempDir/"`).

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't be printing the object inside the loop, just create the ggplot object. Only print when you have the graphic device open that you want.

```
m.list <- foreach(i = 1:length(carats.summary$carat),
    .packages = "ggplot2") %dopar% {
    jcarat = carats.summary$carat[i]
    ggplot(subset(diamonds, carat == jcarat), aes(x = price)) +
        geom_histogram()
}
```

then you can get at them with

```
m.list[[1]]
```

etc...